# Did sysvconfig disappear in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I just installed Ubuntu Server 9.10, and don't have `sysvconfig`, if I `apt-get install sysvconfig`, it tells me that sysvconfig has no installation candidate.

Was sysvconfig removed from Ubuntu 9.10? If so, what alternative can I use? If not, how do I install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/+source/sysvconfig/0.81ubuntu1:

> 0.81ubuntu1 DELETED: Karmic pocket Release in component universe and section admin
>
> - Removal requested on 2009-09-11.
> - Deleted on 2009-09-11 by Martin Pitt
>
> (From Debian) ROM; Sysvinit-utils, a required package, conflicts with it.

As an alternative, you might check out `sysv-rc-conf`:

```
$ apt-cache show sysv-rc-conf
Package: sysv-rc-conf
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin
Installed-Size: 104
Maintainer: Ubuntu MOTU Developers <ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Francesco Pedrini <francesco.pedrini@gmail.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 0.99-6
Depends: libcurses-ui-perl, sysv-rc
Filename: pool/universe/s/sysv-rc-conf/sysv-rc-conf_0.99-6_all.deb
Size: 24168
MD5sum: d40562a6b1b020590a35f7b7f9d23d1c
SHA1: 4cc5df3dc9d7946d0354c1bb3be930a304195fc0
SHA256: 603f7ed049d180db134e8730a229dc93277c22b01558cddce36e5f6ff6a9b67a
Description: SysV init runlevel configuration tool for the terminal
 sysv-rc-conf provides a terminal GUI for managing "/etc/rc{runlevel}.d/"
 symlinks.  The interface comes in two different flavors, one that simply
 allows turning services on or off and another that allows for more fine tuned
 management of the symlinks.  Unlike most runlevel config programs, you can
 edit startup scripts for any runlevel, not just your current one.
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: sysv-rc-conf]

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is to use `sysvconfig` like you want.  Linux is made to allow you to use the tools you *want* to use; if the tool you want isn't immediately available, there are other ways of making it happen.

Since it's not available in the Ubuntu repositories, you'll need to grab the source package (here, from the [last Ubuntu release](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jaunty/sysvconfig) (Jaunty), or here, from the [last Debian release](http://packages.debian.org/source/lenny/sysvconfig) (Lenny)) and [build your own package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo).  (You can also compile and install it without building your own .deb.)

But take care; the package was [removed from Sid](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/sysvconfig/news/20090722T033555Z.html) due to conflicts with `sysvinit-utils`.  That doesn't mean the earlier version will also conflict, but it's something to watch out for.